# How to disable Windows 10 touch style login with digitizer attached

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, digitizer

I attached a digitizer to my PC to help with image editing. The digitizer doesn't have a screen; it mostly acts as a mouse, but with pressure-sensitive input to for image editing.

However, since attaching this to my PC, Windows 10 has started to act like it has a touch screen. In particular, the lock screen doesn't respond to `Esc` to log in; I need to "swipe up" with my mouse to reveal the password input, or press `Ctrl-Alt-Delete`.

It also used to show a giant keyboard at login, but I got rid of that by disabling `Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service`. Disabling this service isn't enough to get rid of the swipe gesture though.

I basically want to disable all touch-related Windows 10 features. I only need the digitizer to work with image editing apps.

Answer (score 0):

The usual method to disable touch in Windows 10 is :

- Run *Start > Device Manager*
- Expand "Human Interface Devices"
- Right-click "HID-compliant touch screen" and select "Disable device"
- Click Yes
- Reboot to test.

Comment: See, I have "HID-compliant digitizer" - I don't have a touchscreen - and I want the device to be *enabled* because I want to use it in graphics applications. What I don't need is Windows for Pen Computing or whatever they're calling it these days - all the affordances that assume you're using the digitizer as a main input. Disabling the Touch Keyboard service has done most of that, the lock screen login issue is the remaining annoyance.